# Content creation and translation workflow

Tags: localization, content

I've developed my Craft website locally ( in fact on a virtual machine on the company intranet, so it's accessible within the company ).
Now it's time to fill the site with contents and translate them for 7 different locales.

My boss is asking me to provide a CSV or similar structured file to let other employees and a translation agency fill the content without accessing the CMS directly.
Is this possible? Is it a good approach?
Keep in mind that the entries have some Matrix field.

Also, is it better to insert the content in the staging environment or in  developement? Or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used it, but probably worth looking at this plugin: https://github.com/boboldehampsink/translate

There are some related feature requests about adding this to Craft core you might want to chime in on as well:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/970

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1173

Answer (score 1):

There is also this:

[Craft CMS Translation Connector](https://www.acclaro.com/our-technology-platform/craft-cms-translation-connector/)

Comment: Wow, seems an impressive localization service. Thanks.